# Interior gradient estimate for uniformly elliptic equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde

I am struggling with a problem like this: In dimension $n\geq 3$,
consider the following uniformly elliptic equation

$$a^{ij}(x)u_{ij}(x)+u_{nn}=0$$

where $i,j = 1, \dots, n-1$, and $\lambda \operatorname{id} < (a^{ij}) < \Lambda \operatorname{id}$. Are there any interior gradient estimates? More specifically, I need the estimate $|u_n|\leq C$ in the interior, where $C$ depends only on $|u|_{L^\infty}$ and the elliptic constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the constant of ellipticity $\nu=\lambda/\Lambda$ close to $1$
for elliptic equations of the form 
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^na^{ij}(x)u_{ij}(x)=0$$ Cordes proved in

> Cordes, Heinz Otto. *Über die erste Randwertaufgabe bei quasilinearen Differentialgleichungen zweiter Ordnung in mehr als zwei Variablen*. (German) Math. Ann. 131 (1956), 278—312. [MR0091400](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0091400)

that provided a solution is smooth enough it belongs locally to $C^{1+\beta_0}$ where $\beta_0\in(0,1)$ depends on $\nu$ and the estimate 
$$
\|\partial_{x_i} u\|_{C^{\beta_0}(B_{1/2})}\le C(n,\nu)\sup_{B_1}|u|
$$
holds. So at least for smooth solutions the required estimate is true.

From the other hand for general $\nu\in(0,1)$, Safonov proved in

> Safonov, M. V. *Unimprovability of estimates of Hölder constants for solutions of linear elliptic equations with measurable coefficients*. (Russian) Mat. Sb. (N.S.) 132(174) (1987), no. 2, 275--288; [translation](http://www.turpion.org/php/paper.phtml?journal_id=sm&paper_id=3167) in Math. USSR-Sb. 60 (1988), no. 1, 269—281 [MR0882838](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=882838)

for $n=3$ that such an estimate is not true. Namely there exists $\nu_0\in(0,1)$ s.t. the estimate above does not holds for any $\nu\in(0,\nu_0]$, $0<\beta<1$, $C>0$.  Though the question posed is not directly answered by this result of Safonov it makes look like a a possibility that the answer can be negative at least for $\nu<\nu_0$ and $n\ge4$ (where one can consider solutions not depending on $x_n$.)

Answer (score 0):

You may also give a look to

G.Di Fazio Lp estimates for divergence form elliptic equations with discontinuous coefficients. Boll. Un. Mat. Ital. A (7) 10 (1996), no. 2, 409–420

where leading coefficients are VMO and boundedness is obtained for any $1 < p < + \infty$.